# String Interpolation in variable

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I have a class which consists only of string constants. Call it Class A. I declare following variable in here.

```
public static string SetScore = $"Score[@Set='{currentSet}']";
```

There is another class, lets call it Class B. I will use my `SetScore` variable in class B. now this class B knows what is `currentSet`.

Problem is Class A does not know what is 'currentSet'.

Is there any solution to this, other than to declare `SetScore` in class B OR using String.Format?

Comment: Does `$"Score[@Set='{MyConstantStringClass.currentSet}']"` not work?

Comment: How about : 
        public static string CurrentSet { get; set; }

        public static string SetScore = string.Format("Score[@Set='{0}']", CurrentSet);

Comment: @Orphid, the value of currentSet is not constant. It will change.

Comment: Do you really want to use string interpolation? You can use `String.Format()` method

Comment: @Praneet, are you saying to declare currentSet in same class where SetScore is declared?? that will kill the purpose, I dont know the value of this currentSet.

Comment: may be  I need to edit my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: @ahsant Yes. Declare that in the same class. So before calling the SetScore you can set the CurrentSet value. Would that work for you ?

Comment: `public static string SetScore = $"Score[@Set='{0}']";`
In the class using `SetScore` use like this `String.Format(SetScore, currentSet)`. Will this solve your problem?

Comment: @geo and Praneet, yes both of your answers solve my problem. but I want to use string interpolation and I want to declare my variable in a separate class.

Comment: you can create `SetScore` in class A. Create an object of class A in class B. Then call `A.SetScore` in the `String.Format()` method. This way you don't need to declare `SetScore` in class B.  Note that interpolation will not work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can't** interpolate like that. The Jiter just wont have any clue of the context or as to when to use that variable.

If you think it through, when should it replace it. On first use? What if you wanted to replace multiple *Representations* in different contexts, which scope should it consider. Sounds very unpredictable

However, if its an consolation. You could do this

```
public static string SetScore = "Score[@Set='{0}']";
...
result = string.Format(SetScore,currentSet)
```

[Interpolated Strings (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

> Used to construct strings. An interpolated string looks like a
>   template string that contains interpolated expressions. An
>   interpolated string returns a string that replaces the interpolated
>   expressions that it contains with their string representations.

**Moreso**

> **You can use an interpolated string anywhere you can use a string
>   literal.** The interpolated string is evaluated each time the code with
>   the interpolated string executes. This allows you to separate the
>   definition and evaluation of an interpolated string.

Comment: I agree this will work, I just want to see if somehow interpolate can work across classes.

Comment: alright, I give up. we cant do it. I have to use String.Format now.